# I can't delete a file from EFI System Partition

Tags: command-line, files, grub, rm, refind

I'm trying to delete a file since I installed rEFInd instead or Grub, I want to remove Grub or just remove "grubx64.efi" from my ESP, to make it disappear in the rEFInd boot screen.

I can mount my ESP like that but I don't know how to delete the file. I'm bad in Linux,

[image: console LS]

Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: `rm -rf /boot/efi/EFI/grub` - and good for you. `grub` sucks.